# Cannot add a controller from List to Widget parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to add a controller from a `List` to my Widget constructor like this :

```
List<TextEditingController> controllers = [
    TextEditingController(),
    TextEditingController(),
    TextEditingController(),
    TextEditingController()
  ];


List<Widget> _cardList = [
    (InputRefNomProduit(
      label: 'Référence',
      content: 'Taper la référence',
      label2: 'Nom du produit',
      content2: '',
      label3: 'Quantité',
      content3: 'Taper la quantité',
      label4: 'Prix',
      content4: 'Taper le prix unitaire',
      fieldController: widget.controllers.first,
      fieldController2: widget.controllers[1],
      fieldController3: widget.controllers[2],
      fieldController4: widget.controllers.last,
    )),
  ];
```

I'm getting this error on all `fieldController` :

```
The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.
```

Comment: You need to share more of your code. It would be great to see the enclosing class

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly initialize a field from a previous one in your constructor.
In your widget constructor, store controllers in a variable temporarily - or declare a function in which you set the second field.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is seem to be the problem that you're trying to access Widget fields when you're declaring them in State.

Second one seems to be *initializer* problem, you can't use fields before they was specifically declared, try to use
`static List<TextEditingController> controllers = [...]`
or declaring `_cardList` in `initState()`

For example:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = [
    TextEditingController(),
    TextEditingController(),
    TextEditingController(),
    TextEditingController()
  ];

  List<Widget> _cardlist = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    List<Widget> _cardList = [
      (InputRefNomProduit(
        label: 'Référence',
        content: 'Taper la référence',
        label2: 'Nom du produit',
        content2: '',
        label3: 'Quantité',
        content3: 'Taper la quantité',
        label4: 'Prix',
        content4: 'Taper le prix unitaire',
        fieldController:  controllers.first,
        fieldController2: controllers[1],
        fieldController3: controllers[2],
        fieldController4: controllers.last,
      )),
    ];
  }
}
```